# ShareOperation.ReportCompleted() results in exception being thrown in UWP

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I am trying to handle the the Share Operation 
Code:

```
protected override async void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
{
     ShareOperation shareOperation = args.ShareOperation;
     Uri uriReceived = null;
     if (shareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.WebLink))
        uriReceived = await shareOperation.Data.GetWebLinkAsync();
     shareOperation.ReportCompleted();
}
```

It crashes at `shareOperation.ReportCompleted();` showing error message as

> "There was no match for the specified key in the index."

I tried searching for this error landing me to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b5c30d1-62e7-41b3-b485-25a4e78f3c99/shareoperationreportcompleted-exception?forum=winappswithht) question, But it seemed it was a problem that went away with later builds, now I'm facing this issue how do you recommend I handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Report sharing status parts of Receive data,

> As a result, you shouldn't call it unless your app is at a point where it can be dismissed by the user.

I guess the reason for the exception is the reporting actions require user's permissions. If you call the `shareOperation.ReportCompleted();` in `ShareTargetActivated` directly you will skip the user's authorization. It seems like it is not allowed.
For the workaround, you can handle the code `shareOperation.ReportCompleted();` in a function like `Button_Click` or `OnGotFocus` . The following code example can resolve your issue.

App.xaml.cs code:

```
protected override async void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        rootFrame = new Frame();
        rootFrame.Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];
        rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.ShareOperation);
    Window.Current.Activate();           
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs code:

```
  ShareOperation shareOperation;
  protected override async void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      Uri uriReceived = null;
      if (shareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.WebLink))
          uriReceived = await shareOperation.Data.GetWebLinkAsync();
      this.shareOperation.ReportCompleted();
      base.OnGotFocus(e);
  }
  protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
      this.shareOperation = (ShareOperation)e.Parameter;
  }
```

More details please reference the official [sharetarget sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ShareTarget).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I guess in my case I should be using protocol not share target.